# Can we make / Register a sharePoint 2013 Site collection as Hub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, hub-site

Is there anyone tried that to make a SharePoint 2013 Site collection to be a hub site. If yes then please help me to the same. if not then why?

Thanks & regards
Gumma Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

We recommend that you select a communication site or a team site that uses the modern template.

The SharePoint 2013 site collection migrated to SharePoint Online is a classic site.

If you use a classic team site, the hub site navigation will only appear on modern pages, including document libraries, lists, and site contents. Hub site settings will only appear on modern pages.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/hub-site-overview

Comment: my question is can we make Sharepoint 2013 site collection as hub site without migrating it to SharePoint Online. So if you tried to do the same please tell me if this is possible or not, if yes please share the steps to be followed.

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no hub sites available for SharePoint server 2013 or later version, You can get modern teams sites or communication sites or SharePoint home page in SharePoint server 2019. but in order to use the hub sites you have to go to Office 365  (SharePoint Online).